# Error 1054 : Unknown Column

Tags: mysql, sql

Updating data in SQL, i had this error:

> ERROR 1054 UNKNOWN COLOMN 'Targa' in WHERE clause;

This is the Query that i made:

```
UPDATE sede SET nome = 'Ford Fiesta', Chilometri = '150.0', AnnoImmatricolazione = '2015', SedeV = '14', Stato = '1', Categoria = '1', Alimentazione = '3', Porte = '1' WHERE Veicolo.Targa = 'CE817HC';
```

and this is the table definition :

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `veicolo`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `veicolo` (
  `Targa` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `Nome` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Chilometri` double NOT NULL,
  `AnnoImmatricolazione` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `SedeV` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `Stato` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `Categoria` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `Alimentazione` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `Porte` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Targa`),
  KEY `_idx` (`SedeV`),
  KEY `_idx1` (`Stato`),
  KEY `c_idx` (`Porte`),
  KEY `Alimentazione` (`Alimentazione`),
  KEY `Categoria` (`Categoria`),
  CONSTRAINT `` FOREIGN KEY (`SedeV`) REFERENCES `sede` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `veicolo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Stato`) REFERENCES `stato` (`IdStato`),
  CONSTRAINT `veicolo_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Porte`) REFERENCES `porte` (`IdPorte`),
  CONSTRAINT `veicolo_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`Alimentazione`) REFERENCES `alimentazione` (`IdAlimentazione`),
  CONSTRAINT `veicolo_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`Categoria`) REFERENCES `categoria` (`IdCategoria`)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a small error:

```
UPDATE sede -- YOU UPDATE THIS TABLE
SET nome = 'Ford Fiesta', 
    Chilometri = '150.0', 
    AnnoImmatricolazione = '2015', 
    SedeV = '14', 
    Stato = '1', 
    Categoria = '1', 
    Alimentazione = '3', 
    Porte = '1' 
WHERE Veicolo.Targa = 'CE817HC'; -- YOU SPECIFY ANOTHER TABLE VEICOLO WHICH ISN'T INCLUDED IN YOUR STATEMENT
```

You need to join the table veicolo or the alias of veicolo is wrong and you want to remove the alias and just use Targa = ...

Comment: Ops ! -.- Thank you a lot, and sorry for my little attention!

Comment: No problemo. :-) You can mark your question as solved if you want. :-)